Package Azure.Identity v1.11.0 and above caused an error with SqlClient and Dynamics 365
Azure.Identity package version 1.11.0 caused an error with SqlClient and Dynamics 365.
I connected to Dynamics 365 using Microsoft Entra Service Principal authentication, and everything worked perfectly. I used SQL Server Management Studio 20.0.70.0.

Also, I have a C# application using Dapper and SqlClient (check the code below).
Everything worked perfectly until I upgraded the Azure.Identity Package to 1.11.0 (updated five days ago). Downgrading it to 1.10.4 will make it work.
I cannot find any solution in Microsoft Docs.
Thank you.
Exception:

ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: AADSTS900023: Specified tenant identifier 'authorize' is neither a valid DNS name, nor a valid external domain. Trace ID: 52222220-3332-3331-3033-222225335233 Correlation ID: fddd3533-aaaa-4fab-8b49-22ea71b32723 Timestamp: 2024-04-14 20:20:52Z

Code:



Does it mean there is no hope of connecting to D365 using SqlClient from C# app?

I've just tested with Azure.Identity 1.13.0 and it seems to be fixed (it was not fixed in 1.12.0)

I finally found it here, But I applied minor modifications to make it work with Dynamics 365. Here is the code

private SqlAuthenticationToken? _sqlAuthenticationToken;

protected Func<SqlAuthenticationParameters, CancellationToken, Task<SqlAuthenticationToken?>> GetTokenCallback()
{
    var tenantId = "[Taken From Azure Portal]";
    var clientId = "[Taken From Azure Portal]";
    var clientSecret = "[Taken From Azure Portal]";
    const string defaultScopeSuffix = ".default";

    var cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

    return TokenCallback;

    async Task<SqlAuthenticationToken?> TokenCallback(SqlAuthenticationParameters ctx, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var validToken = _sqlAuthenticationToken != null && _sqlAuthenticationToken.ExpiresOn.UtcDateTime > dateTimeService.Now;
        if (validToken) return _sqlAuthenticationToken;

        string scope = ctx.Resource.EndsWith(defaultScopeSuffix)
            ? ctx.Resource
            : ctx.Resource + defaultScopeSuffix;

        var token = await cred.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext([scope]), CancellationToken.None);
        _sqlAuthenticationToken = new SqlAuthenticationToken(token.Token, token.ExpiresOn);
        return _sqlAuthenticationToken;
    }
}

Then I modified the creation of SqlConnection to be like this
await using var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
connection.AccessTokenCallback = GetTokenCallback();

One more thing:
You need to modify the connection string from this
"Server=your-app.crm.dynamics.com; Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; Encrypt=True; Database=[db-name]; User Id=[clientId]; Password=[clientSecret]"

to this
"Server=your-app.crm.dynamics.com; Encrypt=True; Database=[db-name];

So I removed User Id, Password, and Authentication.

have you tested with Azure.Identity 1.11.2? There has been some bug fixes in that repository.

Not yet, Thank you for mentioning that. I will check
